# svgOverlay content appears shifted on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I am trying to use an `svgOverlay` to efficiently display a large number of points on a map with **Leaflet**, and I'm encountering a strange "shifting" phenomenon.

*Just to clarify : the reason why I want to use a svgOverlay here, is that I plan to add a small text label next to each point. Using standard Markers with permanent tooltip or divIcon with text is way to slow for the amount of points I want to display (1000-10000). And using GeoJSON does not help because of the lack of text object. On the other hand, performance with an svgOverlay are great for that situation.*

I'm using the following piece of code, which displays a SVG Circle at the location of the Eiffel Tower (location determined thanks to Google Map : 48.858279, 2.294559) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Leaflet SVG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .leaflet-container {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        let latMin = 40;
        let latMax = 53;
        let lngMin = -8;
        let lngMax = 12;

        let svgViewBoxWidth = 1000;
        let svgViewBoxHeight = 1000;

        const map = L.map("map");

        const tiles = L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: "&copy; <a href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a>"
        }).addTo(map);

        const svgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svgElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
        svgElement.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 "+svgViewBoxWidth+" "+svgViewBoxHeight);

        let x = (2.294559 - lngMin) / (lngMax - lngMin) * svgViewBoxWidth;
        let y = (latMax - 48.858279) / (latMax - latMin) * svgViewBoxHeight;

        svgElement.innerHTML = "<circle cx=\"" + x + "\" cy=\"" + y + "\" r=\"4\" stroke=\"white\" stroke-width=\"0.5\" fill=\"green\" />";

        const latLngBounds = L.latLngBounds([[latMin, lngMin], [latMax, lngMax]]);
        map.fitBounds(latLngBounds);

        const svgOverlay = L.svgOverlay(svgElement, latLngBounds, {
            opacity: 1
        }).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But as you can see in this example, the circle is incorrectly positionned, shifted north-west.

I've been conducting tests with larger data sets covering the whole France, and the same issue occurs (there might be a slight "compression" effect on the x axis in fact) :

[image]

What's going on here ? I thought it was a padding/margin style issue but I did not managed to solve it.

**Edit**

Apparently this penomenon is also visible in the svgOverlay tutorial on the official website : https://leafletjs.com/examples/overlays/#svgoverlay

As you can see, the north-east border of the dark square (coordinates : 32, -100) seems to be located somewhere on the horizontal part of the border between Texas and New Mexico :

[image]

Zoom :

[image]

Whereas when I'm searching for the 32, -100 coordinate on OpenStreetMap, the point seems to be located further to the east :

[image]

**Edit 2**

I don't know if this is related, but on the official svgOverlay example ( https://leafletjs.com/examples/overlays/#svgoverlay ), which has its "interactive" option set to "true", when I move my mouse cursor next to the overlay on the right or left side, without being over the overlay, the cursor turns to a pointer, has if there was some sort of margin.